The number of positive integrals of $x_1x_2x_3= y$ in given set.
Let $y$ be an element of the $set A={1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30}$ and $x_1x_2x_3=y$, such that $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are positive integers. The number of positive integral solution of $x_1x_2x_3=y$ is what.
My attempt: After factorising all numbers, one by one I calculated the number of ways which came out to be 52, which is the incorrect answer.
For eg:
For 30, $$ 1*1*30$$
$$2*15*1$$
$$3*5*2$$
Similarly for all numbers in the given set, I did that and find the total arrangements and added them to get 52.
Note: I did calculation by assuming that $x_1, x_2, x_3 $ can have same values.
Where am I going wrong?

It seems like you're missing a lot of ways, so without you further elaborating on what the counts are, it's hard to tell where you gone wrong. EG Note that $ 3 \times 5 \times 1 \neq 30$. $\quad$ My suggestion is to derive a formula to count the number of ways, rather than manually doing so. EG Can you explain why $ y = 2, 3, 5$ have the same number of solutions? How about for $ y = 6, 10, 15$?

For an alternative quick approach that isn't counting numerous specific cases, how many solutions are there to $x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 = 30$? Then, show that we can establish a bijection with your count by ignoring the $x_4$ term.

A quick python search shows that the answer should be like 64 ? )

@AlexeyBurdin yes the answer is 64

Simple hint: reconsider what other possibilities there are for $30$.

Expanding the Calvin Lin's comment to the OP question, and yes, this simplifies the task too much.
Step one: the bijection from $x_1x_2x_3 = y \in A$ to $x_1x_2x_3x_4 = 30$
Let's say $x_4 = \frac{30}{y}$ so there are all possibilities for $x_4$ as a positive divisor of $30$ ($x_1x_2x_3x_4 = 30$ with integer $x_{\{1-4\}} > 0$ implies $x_{\{1-4\}}$ are all divisors of $30$).
Fine, more rigorously:

$x_1x_2x_3 = y \in A \Rightarrow \exists!x_4\in\mathbb{N}: x_1x_2x_3x_4 = 30$ : we take $x_4=\frac{30}{y}$ and there is one and only one such $x_4$ for every $y\in A$.
$x_1x_2x_3x_4 = 30 \Rightarrow \exists!y\in A : x_1x_2x_3 = y$ : we take $y=\frac{30}{x_4}$, $x_4>0 \Rightarrow y>0$ and $x_1x_2x_3x_4 = 30 \Rightarrow x_4|30 \Rightarrow y = \frac{30}{x_4} | 30 \Rightarrow y\in A$.

Step two:
Now the problem is much more simplified. We factor $30 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ into the prime numbers and we need to distribute $2, 3$ and $5$ between $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$.
So we imagine like $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are baskets and $2$ is a red ball, $3$ is a green ball, $5$ is a blue ball. If there's no balls in a basket, then corresponding $x$ equals $1$, otherwise it's the product of the corresponding ball numbers.

As we distribute $3$ different balls into $4$ different baskets independently, there's $4$ possibilities for the red ball, then $16 = 4^2$ possibilities for red and green balls (by the "rule of product") and $64 = 4^3$ for red, green and blue balls, so the answer is $64$.

As told by @EricSnyder,
the other posiblilities for 30 incude that of $3, 10$ and $5, 6$. Taking those, the expression would come $$1 + 7*3+ 3!*7$$ This was done by taking help from what your approach was and the answer comes $64$.
Here I have literally counted all possibilites, and arranged using permutation and combination after jotting all factors in form of triplets.
I am just wondering is there any short and efficient method?
Thanks.

Thanks for confirming!
